# Load images from database CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpmyadmin, photo-gallery

I would like to create a photo gallery, taking images from the database.
I'm using codeigniter.
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpR01.jpg)

[this is a static page located in views/pages/gallery.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlgMT.jpg)

does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to query the database table, get the relevant fields, and return that to a view. In MVC, it looks something like this:

Model:

```
class Portfolio_model extends CI_Model {

    public function get_items() {
        $this->db->select('name, description, image');
        $this->db->order_by('date', 'DESC');
        $q = $this->db->get('tablename'); // your tablename here
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->result();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
class Portfolio extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->model('portfolio_model');
        $data['items'] = $this->portfolio_model->get_items();
        $this->load->view('portfolio', $data);
    }
}
```

View:

```
if (!is_null($items)) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo $item->name . '<br>';
        echo $item->description . '<br>';
        echo 'Image src: ' . base_url() . $item->image . '<br>';  // might need slash after base_url, don't remember
        echo img($item->image);
    }
} else {
    echo 'No items found!';
}
```

Comment: I paste all the code and I edit the table name but I have an error on 2nd row in view folder. Message: Undefined variable: items

Comment: Not possible items is defined here: `$data['items']`. Check again. Some other error must be occurring outside the scope of this code.

Comment: add print_r($data['items')); after $data['items'] in controller and print_r($items) before everything in the view. see if the array is there in both cases.

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: items

Filename: pages/portfolio.php

Line Number: 2

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\canoa\application\views\pages\portfolio.php
Line: 2
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\canoa\application\controllers\Pages.php
Line: 16
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\canoa\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Again refer to my previous comments. The above code is solid. You must have made a mistake somewhere. Post your code on pastebin or something - I'm guessing you aren't using my code verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

Controller -

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('galleryModel');
    $data1['items'] = $this->galleryModel->get_items();
    $this->load->view('gallery', $data1);
}
```

Model -

```
public function get_items() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('gallery');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() != 0){
        return $query->result_array();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

View -

```
<?php
    foreach ($items as $item) {       
        $image_id = $item['image_id'];       
        $name = $item['name'];
        $category = $item['category'];
        $image = $item['image'];
        ?>

    <div class="tile scale-anm <?php echo $category; ?>">
        <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="film-img-gallery" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```